# Good De-Dup tools for SharePoint

Tags: tools, duplicate

What are some good de-dup tools for SharePoint? I tried a powershell method but it doesnt do what it said it do. http://blog.pointbeyond.com/2011/08/24/finding-duplicate-documents-in-sharepoint-using-powershell/

It does not find any MS Office documents. I purposely added bunch of office docs (word, excel, ppt, etc.) with different name but same contents. I heard SP properties takes over the file properties of office and therefore md-5 hash fails.

Comment: What do you need the script to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: @TimGabrhel: It does not find any MS Office documents. I purposely added bunch of office docs (word, excel, ppt, etc.) with different name but same contents. I heard SP properties takes over the file properties of office and therefore md-5 hash fails.

Comment: A comment on the blog article itself highlights that office documents, when stored into different document libraries will not be picked up due to Sharepoint overwriting certain properties.

Answer (score 1):

Not a de-dup tool as such but a script that will allow you to get an inventory output to another source that you can query/filter to find duplicates:

http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2010/08/getting-an-inventory-of-all-sharepoint-documents-using-windows-powershell/

I've used this and found it reasonably handy. A developer could probably take this solution further.

Chris

Comment: Chris is not that simple. We are talking about actual contents of the file. MD-5 is the way to go but it fails for Office documents as SP takes over the file properties of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had somebody ask me something about identifying duplicate files.  I was convinced this would be pretty easy to do in search, but could not find any way to globally identify duplicates and found that the Duplicates keyword property requires a specific item url.

I ended up writing up a full blog post with all of my findings here:  [Finding Duplicate Items and The Duplicates Keyword](http://mikeoryszak.com/2013/04/finding-duplicate-items-and-the-duplicates-keyword/)

In the end it looks like the best option is to alter the PowerShell script by Gary referenced previously, and execute a duplicates search for each document, logging any of the duplicates found.